# Rocket.Chat chat-ops integrations?

Tags: rocket.chat

The https://github.com/RocketChat/Rocket.Chat readme mentions fly-in panel integration and has a sample screenshot - https://raw.githubusercontent.com/Sing-Li/bbug/master/images/dronechatops.png

Is there documentation anywhere to help get started with a fly-in panel chatops integration like that google maps example?

Answer (score 1):

The chatops package was very much added as a proof of concept to show off the kind of customization that could be done in the Rocket.Chat code base.

If you would like to play around with it.  You can goto the `.meteor/packages` file and uncomment the rocketchat:chatops package. Currently on [line 138](https://github.com/RocketChat/Rocket.Chat/blob/develop/.meteor/packages#L138)

The code for it can be found [here](https://github.com/RocketChat/Rocket.Chat/tree/develop/packages/rocketchat-chatops)

You will need to clone the source code as well as run meteor to get up and going.

In the future we will have that ability to do this sort of thing with out needing to edit the source code.